# How to parse of a simple csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv

I have a simple CSV-file like this:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Note ,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
1,,,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,
2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I need to parse it into a 2D array containing **`1`**-s where X are and **`0`** otherwise, ignoring the headers/extra rows.

After reading the docs on the **`csv`** module I wrote a simple script like so:

```
import csv

csvfile = open('input.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile,dialect='excel', delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

data = []

rowCount = 0
for row in reader:
    if(rowCount > 2): #skip first 3 rows (2 empty and 1 label)
        dataRow = []
        for i in xrange(1,len(row[0])):#skip 1st label column
            dataRow.append(1 if row[0][i] == 'X' else 0) #append 1s for X, 0s otherwise
        data.append(dataRow)
    rowCount += 1

print data
```

This gives me the expected output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

for

```
,,,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,
```

The ternary condition could be written as `ord(row[0][i])/88`, but would it be possible to map the each string row to an integer row of ones and zeros?

**Is there's a more 'pythonic' way of writing this ?**

Comment: Numpy is the best way to do the same. have a look at documentation. Also can you add expected output for given input to make the scenario more clear ?

Comment: tip: empty string is `False` in bool context, all other strings are `True`. And `int(False)` is `0`, `int(True)` is `1`

Comment: @all Wow! Very impressive answers, thank you all for the input(+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `delimiter=','`:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
```

Actually:

`dialect='excel', delimiter=','` are defaults and `quotechar='|'` is not need for your example file (keep it if needed). So this is shorter:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

Throw away the first three lines:

```
[next(reader) for _ in range(3)]
```

Read all lines:

```
data = [[1 if entry=='X' else 0 for entry in row[1:]] for row in reader]
```

This equivalent to:

```
data = []
for row in reader:
    data.append([1 if entry=='X' else 0 for entry in row[1:]])
```

Of course, open your file with automatic closing after dedent:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb‘) as csvfile:
    # Put the rest of the algorithm here.
# The file is closed automatically just because continuing detended.
```

This is the prime example of a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html).

Putting it all together:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    [next(reader) for _ in range(3)]
    data = [[1 if entry=='X' else 0 for entry in row[1:]] for row in reader]
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, skipping three rows can be done like:

```
for _ in range(3):
    next(reader)
```

then you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) on the rest:

```
data = [[int(cell == 'X') for cell in line[1:]] for line in reader]
```

This gives you a list of lists:

```
>>> data
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

If efficiency is important and the lines are long, using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) lets you slice each line without creating a new list.

Note that your `delimiter` and `quotechar` settings don't seem to match with the example file, so you might want to double-check that.

Answer (score 1):

one thing i want to add to @jonrsharpe answer.

Pythonic way of using a file is given below. 
This will take care of closing the file for you when your calculation is complete

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    //use the csvfile here
```

Answer (score 0):

### A: Try to avoid overheads ... a smart-enough reader comes from **`numpy.genfromtxt()`**

```
DATA = np.genfromtxt(   aFH,                  # aFH = open( <aFileNAME>, "r" )
                        #kiprows        = 1,  # DeprecationWarning: The use of `skiprows` is deprecated, it will be removed in numpy 2.0.
                        skip_header     = 3,  # twice "..." + "Note,1,2,3.."
                        delimiter       = ",",
                        converters      = { 1:  lambda aString: mPlotDATEs.date2num( datetime.datetime.strptime( aString[1:-1], "%m/%d/%y %H:%M" ) ),
                                            0:  lambda aString: float(                                           aString[1:-1] )
                                            } # left as an example of powers the genfromtxt()'s inline conversters create
                        )
print "DATA has shape of ", DATA.shape

aFH.close()
```

**`converters`** ( asDict ) are the key ( per-column specified ) -- i.e. may post-process **`X`**-s into **`1`**-s and **`isBlank`**-s into **`0`**-s

### + Other benefits

Any serious number crunching is, be it visible or not, based on **`numpy`**. So the imported modules' foot-print does not go as far as if importing **`pandas`** ( very smart and very powerful ) just to import rows of text without any further use of the advanced `DataFrame` capabilities.

Additionally, you may benefit from other, smarter **`numpy`** features, if your **`DATA.size`** grows bigger and bigger. As seen from your sample piece of data, this is a typical situation to use **SPARSE-MATRICE**s, where you do not pay immense-overhead costs associated with handling almost-**empty**-cells ( **`0`**-s ).

This may bring you even a much more memory-compact solution, than the **bool**-ean-MASK array, which still spends more than a few bits on 0-cell-s in the fully-meshed ( **DENSE**-MATRIX ).

### Q: Is there a more-`python`-ic approach?

Hope this will not fire off a war of flames. So as a minimalistic view, let's assume that **`for`**-loops were avoided ( **first plus** - both formally & performance-wise ), a one-liner-populists may be also happy as the whole import process takes one line ( well a bit talkative one, but still one ... *SLOC-line* if anyone seriously cares :o) ). **Finally** the **`lambda`**-inliners are so smart and so powerful **`python`**-ic non-plus-ultra ( get in love with 'em as they both give you immense powers & are so, so, so **`python`**-ic ( though in principle these "Chuck Norrises"-of-code originated in the LISP generation of science about efficient software design in late 50-s of the previous century) )